# when i used the MYSQL struct-type in VS2015, and i found it can't load the character correctly that why?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2015

I had already set up the project's environment and build project succeed,but it will happen interruption because the hmodule it return NULL. I found the reason in debug is character loading bad, but i can't deal with it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "mysql.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"libmysql.lib")

int main()
{
    MYSQL mysql; // it can't load the character correctly
    ... 
    return 0;
}
```

this is the runing picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twrmu.jpg)

Comment: `memset` is commented out and the debugger is on the line before `mysql_init` - what you are seeing is uninitialised memory.

Comment: Thank you.The question is solved. I found the reason is in my careless. when i create project, i should move the libmysql.lib and libmysql.dll files into debug's file.